# pass value of HTML input text to server side variable

Tags: vbscript

I have this sample code:

**vbscript:**

```
dim conn,rs,sql, getval
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open dbconnection

sql = "Select * FROM tableDetails"
rs.Open sql, conn
getval = desc.value
if getval  <> "" Then <---- I want to get value from input text with id of 'desc'
response.write("it has value")
end if
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" name="test" action="sample.asp">
  <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc" value="<%=rs("desc")%>" />

 </form>
```

How would I get the value from input text field and pass it to serverside variable? please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't requesting the value correctly, but what you want can easily be done.

```
dim conn,rs,sql, getval
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs   = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open dbconnection
sql = "Select * FROM tableDetails"
rs.Open sql, conn
If not rs.eof Then    'always include this to make sure your DB query has results, otherwise you could get an error if the query is empty

    getval = Request.Form("desc")
    If getval<>"" Then 
       response.write("it has value")
    End If

End If
```

Another option is to grab the value from the HTML page and insert it back into the DB.  Whenever you get a value, ALWAYS clean it to protect your DB

```
getval= CleanInput(Request("desc"))   'clean it

SQL = "INSERT INTO tableDetails (desc) VALUES('"& getval &"');" 

Function CleanInput(temp) '------------------------------------------
    temp = Trim(Replace(temp,"'","`"))
    CleanInput = temp
End Function'------------------------------------------
```